# Junit tests in Eclipse are failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

My tests were running fine but then I had to reinstall Eclipse.  Now even the simplest test fails with the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

I've tried following the advice in responses to similar questions but I cannot resolve the error.  I've added the Junit library to the project, I've tried adding junit-4.11.jar and junit-4.10.jar to the classpath, and I've tried adding hamcrest-core-1.3.jar to the classpath.

I'm using Eclipse 4.3.2 on a Mac running OS 10.9 with java version "1.6.0_65"

Here is the trace from Eclipse:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10) at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59) at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26) at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59) at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.(JUnit4TestReference.java:33) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ... 25 more

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try  once adding with hamcrest-all-1.3.jar in classpath

Comment: I right clicked on the project, selected build path -> configure build path -> libraries -> add external jars and added hamcrest-all-1.3.jar.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by making sure the run configuration had the hamcrest-all-1.3.jar in the bootstrap classpath